# Orbeon - empty value as 0

Tags: orbeon, xforms

I have many input fields in Orbeon in Form builder as `war1`, `war2` , `war3`, and not all fields have to be filled. I want to make a sum of this fields (I can't make them repeatable because I want to reset it via web service), but when some of the fields are empty, the sum doesn't display. Using an initial value doesn't resolve the problem because I want to set values via a web service, and sometimes the values returned by the service are empty string.

Comment: I have made something like this: In calculated value i typed: if(string(current()) = '') then 0 else current()

Comment: But it's not perfect, because I have 0 in all fields and when i want type some value i have to delete 0 first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your fields are named `war1`, `war2`, `war3`, use:

```
sum(($war1, $war2, $war3)[string() castable as xs:decimal], 0.0)
```

And for some background on this, see the blog post [Formulas for summing values, done right](http://blog.orbeon.com/2013/08/formulas-for-summing-values-done-right.html), which is exactly about this topic. (The very fact that there is a blog entry about this tells you that this is rather subtle, which makes your question all the more justifiable.)